# The definition of directional derivative for the function on manifold.

Tags: differential-geometry, definition, smooth-manifolds, tangent-spaces

The definition of $D_v$ (maybe this is directional derivative) and a property(Leibnitz rule) are  written as follows, but I wonder this is correct.

---

Let $X$ be manifold, $U\subset X$ be open, $p\in U.$

For $v=[\ \ell \ ]\in T_p X$, define $D_v : C^\infty (U,\mathbb R) \to \mathbb R$ as $f\mapsto \dfrac{d}{dt}\Bigg|_{t=0} \dfrac{d(f\circ \ell)}{dt}(t)$.

Then we can see $D_v$ satisfies Leibnitz rule ; $D_v(fg)=f(p)D_v(g)+g(p)D_v (f)$.

---

I think $D_v$ is defined as directional derivative. If so, I think $D_v$ should be defined as $f\mapsto \dfrac{d}{dt}\Bigg|_{t=0}(f\circ \ell)(t) \left(=(f\circ \ell)'(0)\right)$.

If I use the definition $f\mapsto \dfrac{d}{dt}\Bigg|_{t=0}(f\circ \ell)(t) \left(=(f\circ \ell)'(0)\right)$, I can see the Leibnitz rule by simple calculation, but if I use the definition $f\mapsto \dfrac{d}{dt}\Bigg|_{t=0} \dfrac{d(f\circ \ell)}{dt}(t)$, I cannot see the Leibnitz rule, so I think this definition $f\mapsto \dfrac{d}{dt}\Bigg|_{t=0} \dfrac{d(f\circ \ell)}{dt}(t)$ is wrong.

Is this mistake of author ?

Comment: I suppose it is just a typo.

Comment: The name is **Leibniz**. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gottfried_Wilhelm_Leibniz.

Comment: What is your definition of the tangent space? Equivalence classes of curves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is wrong, but certainly a typo. It would be correct to write
$$D_v(f) =  \dfrac{d(f\circ \ell)}{dt}(t)\Bigg|_{t=0}$$
or
$$D_v(f) =  \dfrac{d}{dt}\Bigg|_{t=0} (f\circ \ell)(t) .$$

Comment: Is it equal to $(f\circ \ell)'(0)$ ?

Comment: @inc Yes, of course. $g'(a) = \frac d{dt}\Big|_{t=a} g(t) = \frac{dg}{dt}\Big|_{t=a} = \frac{dg}{dt}(a)$.